# What frequency wifi is my Chromebook connected to?

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os

Is my Chromebook connected to 2.4 Ghz or 5 Ghz wifi? How can I tell? My router has both with the same network name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Settings / Network select the connected network and expand 'Advanced'. The frequency field will be 5180 for 5 GHz wifi, or 2412 for 2.4 GHz wifi.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connected on the 5 GHz band, then your frequency will be in the ranges of 5150 to 5350 MHz or 5725 to 5850 MHz.

@Colonel Panic - When you looked at your Frequency, it just happened to be 5180 (5.180 GHz). Same for 2.5 Ghz, it will be a range 2401 to 2484 MHz, which your 2412 (2.412 GHz) is within.